Prevent duplication entry based on amount
So I'm writing an inventory for a game in lua, but I have some issues when it saves the inventory.
The function code is as follows
function SaveInventory(source, offline)
    local source = source
    local xPlayer = ESX.GetPlayerFromId(source)
    local PlayerName = xPlayer.getName()

    items = AllItemData[source]

    local ItemsJson = {}

    if items and table.type(items) ~= 'empty' then
        for slot, item in pairs(items) do
            if items[slot] then
                for k, v in pairs(items) do
                    ItemsJson[#ItemsJson + 1] = {
                        name = v.name,
                        amount = v.amount,
                        info = v.info,
                        type = v.type,
                        slot = v.slot,
                    }
                end

            end
        end

        MySQL.prepare('UPDATE users SET inventory = ? WHERE identifier = ?', { json.encode(ItemsJson), xPlayer.identifier })
    end

end

The inventory saves fine, however, with every item it duplicates and I wonder why it's doing that.
So with just a phone, it returns
[
  {
    "name": "phone",
    "amount": 1,
    "slot": 6,
    "info": []
  }
]

However if I add another item lets say a male id card to the inventory, it doubles the entry as such
[
  {
    "name": "idcard_m",
    "amount": 1,
    "slot": 7,
    "info": []
  },
  {
    "name": "phone",
    "amount": 1,
    "slot": 6,
    "info": []
  },
  {
    "name": "idcard_m",
    "amount": 1,
    "slot": 7,
    "info": []
  },
  {
    "name": "phone",
    "amount": 1,
    "slot": 6,
    "info": []
  }
]

As far as I can see there is nothing wonky in the code, so I hope a fresh pair of eyes can shed some light.
The expected behavior is that json.encode should return unduplicated as such
[
  {
    "name": "idcard_m",
    "amount": 1,
    "slot": 7,
    "info": []
  },
  {
    "name": "phone",
    "amount": 1,
    "slot": 6,
    "info": []
  }
]


Why are you testing if items[slot] then? You already know that items[slot] is not nil since slot was handed to you as a key. Perhaps more importantly, why are you iterating over items twice in a nested loop?

Turns out I forgot to remove that, I think during the building phase I iterated twice, to make sure all the data came back the same, and forgot about that causing issues. Thanks for pointing that out because after 9 days straight looking at the same code, you can miss a thing or two
